# Broadcast Receiver-Android

Tags: android

i used `DATE_CHANGED` intent filter to find out new date.(i.e) when time switches `from 12:59 to 00:00.`
But the problem is,the `DATE_CHANGED` intent filter is not working when time switch from 12:59 to 00:00.
Can somebody please give the answer.
Is there any possible way to find out when new day is arrived.

Comment: which intent filter you use in your manifest file ?

Comment: I believe this intent is only sent when the date has changed due to a network update or when a different date is set by the user

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: Oops! date will change when time changes from 11:59 to 00:00 or 23:59 to 00:00 not from 12:59.

Comment: I think `AlarmManager` is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Service` to check for date regularly, when the day changes call some method